# how to use .html() in jquery without clearing events attached to selectors?

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to use jquery function .html() but I noticed that it clears all events that are attached to the selectors. Is there a way around this issue? I want to change the content and keep the events.

Answer (score 1):

when attaching events, use the [$.live() function](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead.

edit: or use [$.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) for shorter and easier to read code

Comment: delegate is just a short-hand for a more complicated statement using live, but it is better.

Comment: Thank you, but I am making changes to an external page so I do not have control over attaching events.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize "event delegation".

To do this, you assign the event handler to a common ancestor container, then only fire the handler if an element that received the event is the correct one.

jQuery makes this easy with the [`delegate()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method.

```
$('#myContainer').delegate('.someElement', 'click', function() {
    // the code will run when an element with the class "someElement" is clicked
});
```

Given this generic example, whenever an element inside `#myContainer` that has the class `someElement` receives a `click` event, the handler will be invoked.